# Tricky issue with using xslt with badly formed html

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml

I am fairly new to xslt (2.0) and am having some trouble with a tricky issue. Essentially I have a badly formatted html file like below:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <p> text 1 </p>
    <div> <p> text 2</p> </div>
    <p> Here is a list
        <ul>
            <ol> 
                <li> ListItem1 </li>
            <li> ListItem1 </li>
        </ol>
        <dl>
            <li> dl item </li>
            <li> dl item2 </li>
        </dl>
    </ul> 
    <div>
    <p> I was here</p>
    </div>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to put it into a nicely formated XML file. In my xslt file I recursively check if all children of a p or div are other p's or div's and just promote them, other wise I use them as stand alone paragraphs. I extended this idea so that if a p or div with a child list show up properly but don't promote the list children.

A problem that I am having is that the output xml I get is the following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>
    <body>

    <p> text 1 </p>
     <p> text 2</p> 
     Here is a list
    <ul>
        <ol> 
            <li> ListItem1 </li>
            <li> ListItem1 </li>
        </ol>
        <dl>
            <li> dl item </li>
            <li> dl item2 </li>
        </dl>
    </ul> 

    <p> I was here</p>



</body>
</html>
```

"Here is a list" needs to be in paragraph tags too! I am going crazy trying to solve this ...
Any input/links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but HTML Tidy does a great job of handling this kind of issue without requiring you to fuss with the guesswork. If you want XSLT advice you probably need to post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a short but complete solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "div[descendant::div or descendant::p]
  |
   p[descendant::div or descendant::p]
  ">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "div[descendant::div or descendant::p]/text()
  |
   p[descendant::div or descendant::p]/text()
  ">
   <xsl:element name="{name(..)}"
        namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p> text 1 </p>
      <p> text 2</p>
      <p> Here is a list

      </p>
      <ul>
         <ol>
            <li> ListItem1 </li>
            <li> ListItem1 </li>
         </ol>
         <dl>
            <li> dl item </li>
            <li> dl item2 </li>
         </dl>
      </ul>
      <p> I was here</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! It is extremely difficult to find people who know xslt. Cheers